# Is the minimum investment the same as minimum balance for a mutual fund?

Tags: mutual-funds, minimum-payment

If my mutual fund's minimum investment is $10K, does that mean I can sell shares after a year and fall below $10K without penalty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Minimum investment" is what you need to put into the account to open it.

They may charge you maintenance fees if you fall below some amount, but once you're in you're in.  They'll be more than happy to take their management fee. :)

Comment: Mostly the minimum investment is because they don't feel like processing a bunch of small transactions. When your money's just sitting there it's not a problem.

Comment: They also don't want the cost of e.g., sending statements and reports for tiny accounts. Sending an annual report costs the same for a $100 account as for a $1,000,000 one, but they're getting a lot more management fees from the latter.

Answer (score 5):

Read the prospectus. It should tell you if there's a minimum balance requirement, and if so, what the fees/penalties are for falling below that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. The fund may have a minimum requirement that lets the value falling below the minimum due to the market have no impact, but they may not allow withdrawals if you fail to meet the balance. 
Otherwise, you could open the account for $10K and withdraw $9000 the next day.